# $locationProvider.html5Mode is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hey I am trying to enable html5 in my angular project based on this blog but using ui-router
https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag and the angular docs

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Basically I keep getting an error saying that html5Mode is not a function and it's confusing me as to why.

I have included it in my config file and adapted the urls including a base url. It all works fine but as soon as I add

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode()
```

I get an error saying it's not a function. So I guess my question is has the function name changed, am I missing a dependency,  and if not why is this not working? In advance thank you for taking the time to help me.

```
   angular.module('myApp', [
   'ui.router',
   'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngAnimate',
   'myApp.version'

   ]). 
config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {


    $locationProvider.html5Mode({

        enabled: true

    });

  $stateProvider
      .state('home' , {

        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'app/landingPage/landingPage.html'

      })

      .state('landingPage', {

        url: '/landing-page',
        templateUrl: 'app/homePage/homePage.html'


  })



 }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to inject $urlRouterProvider as your second param.

Comment: I must wait 8 mins to accept your answer. You are a living legend sir

Comment: I had toyed with leaving a "you'll kick yourself when you see it" answer. Dont worry. We've all been there.

Comment: Haha that would have been hell...... I was there thinking to myself "this should work like what the ****"